# not able to navigate using RedirectToAction

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am notable to naviagate to another page using Redirect ie when result is false, then i would like to navigate to exception page which is not happening.

```
 public ActionResult IsLoginExsit(CustomerDO loginData)
    {          


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginData.UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginData.Password))
        {
            bool result = Businesss.Factory.BusinessFactory.GetRegistrations().IsLoginExist(loginData.UserName, loginData.Password);
            if (result)
            {
                CustomerDO custInfo = new CustomerDO();
                JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult();
                jsonResult.Data = loginData;
                custInfo = Businesss.Factory.BusinessFactory.GetRegistrations().GetCustInfoByUserName(loginData.UserName);
                SessionWrapper.SetInSession("CustomerID", custInfo.Id);
                SessionWrapper.SetInSession("CustomerFirstName", custInfo.FirstName);
                SessionWrapper.SetInSession("CustomerLastName", custInfo.LastName);
                return jsonResult;
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("UnAuthorized", "Exceptions");
            }
        }
        return View();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be invoking this action using AJAX. If you want to redirect this should be done on the client side in the success callback of this AJAX call using `window.location.href`. So for example you could adapt your action so that in case of error it returns a JSON object containing the url to redirect to:

```
else
{
    return Json(new { errorUrl = Url.Action("UnAuthorized", "Exceptions") }); 
}
```

and then inside your AJAX success callback:

```
success: function(result) {
    if (result.errorUrl) {
        window.location.href = result.errorUrl;
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```